# ADD a <link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> node to the xml file using c# System.Xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i'm creating a xml file using System.Xml....so first i've got so far...

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docNode = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        xmldoc.AppendChild(docNode);

        XmlNode Doc = xmldoc.CreateDocumentType("html", "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd", null);
        xmldoc.AppendChild(Doc);
        //XmlNode htmlNode = htmlNode.;

        XmlNode xmlRoot, xmlNode;

        xmlRoot = xmldoc.CreateElement("head");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlRoot);

        xmlNode = xmldoc.CreateElement("Child");
        xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlNode);
        xmlNode.InnerText = "This is the first Child";

         xmlNode.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;

        xmlNode = xmldoc.CreateElement("Child2");
        xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlNode);
        xmlNode.InnerText = "This is the second Child";

        xmlNode = xmldoc.CreateElement("Child3");
        xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlNode);
        xmlNode.InnerText = "This is the third Child";

        string filename = @"D:\Anusha\xmlFiles" + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".xml";

         string filename = @"c:\NewXML" + ".xml" or @"c:\whatever" + ".xml"

        xmldoc.Save(filename);
```

i need to add .css file

to my xml document...
how do i do it???

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong try this

```
 <?xml-stylesheet href="common.css" type="text/css"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="modern.css" title="Modern" media="screen" type="text/css"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="classic.css" alternate="yes" title="Classic" media="screen, print" type="text/css"?>
```

Comment: i want to add link using c# code....like XmlNode Doc = xmldoc.CreateDocumentType("html", "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd", null);
        xmldoc.AppendChild(Doc);.......is there a way 2 create link node like mayb...xmldoc.Createlinktype()?????

Comment: i want c# code 2 create link node... like xmldoc.CreateElement()....  xmlRoot = xmldoc.CreateElement("head");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlRoot);.... this creats a <head>... </head>....i want code or meathod 2 create <link href=“template.css” rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css”/> in the xml file...

Comment: @ Dorababu...  is my explanation ok??